# Random number for login verifaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When i originally wrote my website in php i had a random key generator for the web site don't know if im looking for the wrong thing in search or what but i cant find an example!

i don't have any code atm just trying to find an example before i go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.

Comment: looks like that may work thx. oh heres the link for anyone else reading this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html